# I'm seeing the following error when installing TensorFlow :

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to install TensorFlow through pip on Windows 10

> pip3 install tensorflow

I got the following error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info"  failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qzzubrm_\protobuf\

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Questioning with link is not a good approach as link might be broken over time. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will make the required changes.